# Barebones JVM environment

Tags: architecture, jvm, benchmarking

Need to setup a barebones environment to benchmark code with as little enviromental external system overhead as possible at runtime to get as stable reports overtime as possible. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This seems more like an OS configuration question than a programming question.  As such, it might be a better fit for Super User.  It's kinda vague, though, so it might get closed there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear because there are many variables which you may or may not be interested in.

One possibility is to install a brand new Windows or Linux system (if either of those OS's is relevant, or at least not detrimental to your goal), install only the JRE and your benchmark software, disconnect from the internet, and run your tests.

If you're looking to use a JVM on other systems, or you feel the official JRE is too cumbersome and will affect your results, you much wish to check out http://oss.readytalk.com/avian/ -- a JVM which is relatively easy to port to several arbitrary systems. Of course there are other similar portable alternatives.